# How to speed up my website asp.net c# which I test it with chrome

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, performance

I am trying to fix my issue about performance
when I test in chrome show me this problem:

- Reduce server response times (TTFB) 10 second
- Eliminate render-blocking resources 4 second
- Minimize Critical Requests Depth

I disable viewstate and did cache SqlCacheDependency and minify CSS and JS,
used CDN for bootstrap and jequery. Used compression in html.

And this code for Css and JS in Site.master

What I can do more?

I am trying a lot please help me

```
<link href="../css/MYStyle.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link href="../css/JF-flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"  />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script async src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: There are tools like Dot Trace that let you pin point speed issues by telling you which methods take the most time to complete etc